# error when starting wifi interface: failed to load regulatory.db

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I `bitbake`'d my yocto image but when I start my wifi interface on the target I see an error such as:

```
platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the [`wireless-regdb`](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory/wireless-regdb):

```
 IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " wireless-regdb-static"
```

Note the `static` which will include the necessary firmware files.
If the problem persists you may suffer from a bug which has been discussed is [this thread](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=892229). A solution can be found within this thread as well, which would be

> Download wireless-regdb 2017.12.23, untar, and copy regulatory.db and
> regulatory.db.p7s to /lib/firmware;.

[See reply by gerardo diaz]. In my case this made the error disappear during boot.

Furthermore, ensure that the kernel modules are enable as Cleiton Bueno pointed out.

*Note*: I'm posting this rather for documentation and hope this might help others, too.

Answer (score 2):

See if your kernel has the settings:

```
CONFIG_CFG80211_REQUIRE_SIGNED_REGDB=y
CONFIG_CFG80211_USE_KERNEL_REGDB_KEYS=y
```

You can confirm with:

`zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_CFG80211`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Both options are enabled in the kernel configuration (checked through bitbakes menuconfig). The flag to produce `/proc/config.gz` (`CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` ?) was not set. Thus, I'm recompiling to see if it actually also contains that flag.

Comment: It's a little while ago but I finally confirmed that both kernel modules are enabled (`y`) and `crda` as well as the `wireless-regdb` are installed. The problem remains. Any other suggestions what might be missing? Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: The missing bit was the actual regulatory.db and regulatory.db.p7s files which I pointed out in my answer below. This resolved the issue.

Comment: For Fedora 33 the command is: `cat /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/config | grep CONFIG_CFG80211`